# Implementing multiprocessing with multiple geoprocesses

Tags: arcpy, raster, parallel-processing, subprocess

I am relatively new to Python and thought I would give a stab at multiprocessing. I have a script that runs well in IDLE or as an ArcMap toolbox script. After perusing these forums and docs.python, I made an attempt at incorporating my working script into a multiprocessing one. However similar working examples on this forum are, none address data processing as I would like to. I hope it is feasible.

Basically, the script moves through a list of elevation rasters (ERDAS IMG format), extracting cells below a threshold, and finally merging them together. I am currently running the script in the command prompt, as everything else opens new windows, or crashes in an attempt to. The script gives the illusion that it works fine, except it seems to move on to the final merge before waiting for the workers to completely finish.

I have looked at several examples and few seem to have more than a couple of processes in the worker function. None of which are arcpy geoprocesses. So I guess my questions are essentially

1. Should I be using something other than pool.apply_async, such as pool.map or pool.apply?
2. Am I properly returning the path of the final polygon to the resultList?

   ## Import modules

   import arcpy, os, math
   from arcpy import env
   from arcpy.sa import *
   import multiprocessing
   import time

   ## Check out licenses

   arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")

   ## Define functions

   def worker_bee(inputRaster, scratch, addNum):
   (path, lName) = os.path.split(inputRaster)
   (sName, ext) = os.path.splitext(lName)
   nameParts = sName.split("_")
   nameNumber = nameParts[-1]

   ```
    # Create scratch subfolder if not exists
    subFolder = scratch + "\\" + nameNumber + "_output" 
    if not os.path.exists(subFolder):os.makedirs(subFolder)
    # Set workspace to subfolder
    arcpy.env.workspace = subFolder
    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=True
    arcpy.env.extent = "MAXOF"

    # Local Variables
    Expression = "Shape_Area >= 100"

    poly1 = subFolder + "\\poly1.shp"
    poly2 = subFolder + "\\poly2.shp"
    poly3 = subFolder + "\\poly3.shp"
    poly4 = subFolder + "\\poly4.shp"
    poly5 = subFolder + "\\poly5.shp"
    poly6 = subFolder + "\\poly6.shp"
    poly7 = subFolder + "\\poly7.shp"
    outName = scratch + "\\ABL_" + nameNumber + ".shp"

    #### Perform calculations ###
    # Map Algebra (replace -9999 with 9999)
    inRasterCon = Con(inputRaster, 9999, inputRaster, "Value = -9999")
    # Filter DEM to smooth out low outliers
    filterOut = Filter(inRasterCon, "LOW", "DATA")
    # Determine raster MINIMUM value and calculate threshold
    filterMinResult = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(filterOut, "MINIMUM")
    filterMin = filterMinResult.getOutput(0)
    threshold = (float(filterMin) + float(addNum))
    # Map Algebra (values under threshold)
    outCon = Con(filterOut <= threshold, 1, "")
    arcpy.RasterToPolygon_conversion(outCon, poly1, "SIMPLIFY", "Value")
    # Dissolve parts
    arcpy.Dissolve_management(poly1, poly2, "", "", "SINGLE_PART", "DISSOLVE_LINES")    
    # Select parts larger than 100 sq m
    arcpy.Select_analysis(poly2, poly3, Expression)
    # Process: Eliminate Polygon Part
    arcpy.EliminatePolygonPart_management(poly4, poly5, "PERCENT", "0 SquareMeters", "10", "CONTAINED_ONLY")
    # Select parts larget than 100 sq m
    arcpy.Select_analysis(poly5, poly6, Expression)
    # Simplify Polygon
    arcpy.SimplifyPolygon_cartography(poly6, poly7, "BEND_SIMPLIFY", "3 Meters", "3000 SquareMeters", "RESOLVE_ERRORS", "KEEP_COLLAPSED_POINTS")
    # Smooth Polygon
    outShape = arcpy.SmoothPolygon_cartography(poly7, outName, "PAEK", "3 Meters", "FIXED_ENDPOINT", "FLAG_ERRORS").getOutput(0)
    ### Calculations complete ###

    # Delete scratch subfolder
    arcpy.Delete_management(subFolder)

    print("Completed " + outShape + "...")
    return outShape
   ```

   resultList = []
   def log_result(result):
   resultList.append(result)

   if **name** == "**main**":
   arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=True

   ```
    # Read in parameters
    inFolder = raw_input("Input Folder: ")#arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
    addElev = raw_input("Number of elevation units to add to minimum: ")

    # Create scratch folder workspace
    scratchFolder = inFolder + "\\scratch" 
    if not os.path.exists(scratchFolder):os.makedirs(scratchFolder)

    # Local variables
    dec_num = str(float(addElev) - int(float(addElev)))[1:]
    outNameNum = dec_num.replace(".", "")
    outMerge = inFolder + "\\ABL_" + outNameNum + ".shp"

    # Print core usage
    cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    print("Using " + str(cores) + " cores...")

    #Start timing
    start = time.clock()

    # List input tiles
    arcpy.env.workspace = inFolder
    inTiles = arcpy.ListRasters("*", "IMG")
    tileList = []
    for tile in inTiles:
        tileList.append(inFolder + "\\" + tile)

    # Create a Pool of subprocesses
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(cores)

    print("Adding jobs to multiprocessing pool...")
    for tile in tileList:
        # Add the job to the multiprocessing pool asynchronously
        pool.apply_async(worker_bee, (tile, scratchFolder, addElev), callback = log_result)

    # Clean up worker pool; waits for all jobs to finish
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    # Get the resulting outputs (paths to successfully computed breakline polygons)
    #print("Getting resulting outputs...")
    #results = [job.get() for job in jobs]

    # Merge the temporary outputs
    print("Merging temporary outputs into shapefile " + outMerge + "...")
    arcpy.Merge_management(resultList, outMerge)

    # Clean up temporary data
    print("Deleting temporary data ...")
    for result in results:
        try:
            arcpy.Delete_management(result)
        except:
            pass

    # Stop timing and report duration
    end = time.clock()
    duration = end - start
    hours, remainder = divmod(duration, 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
    print("Completed in %d:%d:%f" % (hours, minutes, seconds))
   ```

Comment: Just to clarify, if you took out the final merge step the code actually executes without error using multiple cores?

Comment: It executes without errors with multiple cores, but each worker does not complete all tasks.  Each worker stops after Dissolve, not finished the remaining steps of the function.

Answer (score 2):

I think this may be an example of what you are looking for...check out this Esri article on multiprocess geocoding. It says, "Download the tool even if you’re not a geocoder, you may be able to leverage the logic to parallelize other geoprocessing jobs – and if you do, don’t forget to share your own tools!" "... lets you leverage all available CPU cores on your local machine, or all available Server instances on a remote server."

http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2011/05/04/multiprocess-geocoding/
Also here, http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2011/08/29/multiprocessing/

Comment: thank you for the answer.  I actually used the second link for reference when writing my code.  I'll look at the subprocess example and let you know how it goes. Thanks again.